# What is the official stance on text wrapping edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

If a question contains a code block that causes a lot of horizontal scrolling e.g:

```
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
 }];
 [task resume];
```

and where the code can be reformatted without affecting the question e.g:

```
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
                                  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, 
                                  NSURLResponse *response, 
                                  NSError *error) {
 }];
 [task resume];
```

should it be edited? Or is this considered a trivial edit that will waste time in the edit queue?

Comment: I typically edit these. Maybe not if they only have to scroll for a few characters. But in this example I definitely would. Just make sure if follows the languages standards for wrapping (i.e indentation). As always, make sure you fix anything else you find but this isn't minor. Scrolling back and forth, especially to follow *someone else's* code, is a pain. <-- stamped "codeMagic official"

Comment: Scrollbars suck. I hate having to horizontally and vertically scroll through code. I want to be able to quickly glance over the structure of the entire code. It makes me grumpy when parts of it are hidden away by scrollbars.

Comment: Sure, edit them, but that’s a really bad reformatting of the original.

Comment: @false: And yet, it is a vast improvement over the original.  In other news, where did that diamond come from? :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey: [Your answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252763/1497596) to this similar (but closed) question actually answers this question quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I edit these ( I used to call that *unscroll*) specially if the issue the question (or answer) tries to address is in the part that isn't visible.

So if I go: *huh, there is nothing wrong with that* only to find the culprit after I scrolled to the end and edit is warranted.

9 out of 10 of these cases it is not the only problem in the post. Often there is more stuff to fix like removing noise, spelling, grammar, salutations, greetings, tags in titles, correct capitalization, reducing wall-of-texts, wrong or missing tags, etc.

If you fix those as well you are not wasting time of reviewers. Make sure to add a clear comment what you edit also if it is just reducing the need for scrolling. That will reduce the chance that reviewers mistake your edit for too minor.